# Sequelize umzug migrations Error: Invalid umzug storage

Tags: umzug

when I am run this code it showing error Invalid umzug storage.
the code are given bellow:

```
const { Umzug } = require('umzug');
const db = require('../../storage/models');
const umzug = new Umzug({
storage: 'Sequelize',
storageOptions: {
sequelize: db.sequelize, // here should be a sequelize instance, not the Sequelize module
modelName: 'SequelizeMeta',
columnName: 'name'
},
migrations: {
path: '../../storage/models'
},
logger: console,
});
exports.dbmigrate = async (req, res, next) => {
const executed = await umzug.executed();
res.send(executed);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated Umzug migration tool has some changes in the syntax. I have modified the code you posted. Please try with this code. It should work.
Reference Link: [Docs](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug)

```js
const {
  Umzug,
  SequelizeStorage
} = require('umzug');
const db = require('../../storage/models');
const sequelize = db.sequelize;
const umzug = new Umzug({
  storage: new SequelizeStorage({ sequelize }),
  storageOptions: {
    sequelize: db.sequelize, // here should be a sequelize instance, not the Sequelize module
    modelName: 'SequelizeMeta',
    columnName: 'name'
  },
  migrations: {
    path: '../../storage/models'
  },
  logger: console,
});
exports.dbmigrate = async (req, res, next) => {
  const executed = await umzug.executed();
  res.send(executed);
};
```